# How can I change this WooCommerce cart icon into text

Tags: css, woocommerce, css-selectors, icons, cart

Need help. How can I change this cart icon?

[image]

I want to change it to an image icon. Also, I need it to put the code in my Child-theme stylesheet.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry for the post title it was a mistake "Typo" - How can I change this WooCoomerce cart icon into and image.

Comment: With [CSS `background` property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)